# Is it possible to make a notebook behave like text editor such as Sublime Text with regard to code formatting?

Tags: front-end, customization, stylesheet, syntax-highlighting

Can *Mathematica*, natively or otherwise, behave more like a conventional text editing tool such as Sublime Text or Notepad++ when it comes to code formatting and syntax highlighting?

I have seen some users use *Mathematica* through power shell or terminal – I don't want to do this as it seems to defeat the instant feedback in terms of plotting one gets in a Notebook, but formatting code in the more traditional way would be nice.

At the moment I put everything in code blocks (`Alt + 8`) which mostly does the trick. There also exist packages in Sublime Text that allow syntax highlighting and code formatting, but then you have to copy your text over to a *Mathematica* Notebook – tedious!

Here is an example of Sublime Text with Wolfram Language syntax highlighting, I'm not necessarily looking for this exact style, and I would prefer to be able to keep the ability of working in *Mathematica* rather than coding in one environment an execute in another:

[image]

Comment: What portion of code formatting are you looking for? That’s a broad topic. If you want block indentation or autoindentation, it’s possible to get that baked into the system.

Comment: Syntax highlighting, block indentation, the dashed lines one sees in Sublime to show bracket pairs...as close as to sublime text really -- in my view Sublime Text is near perfect when it comes to code formatting.

Comment: Syntax highlighting already mostly works. What about that would you like to see changed? I’m reasonably certain I can customize any of these things, just wondering what you’d like different. The dashed lines can also be set up (sorta) using a setting that will display spaces and tabs as very light dots. That specific look however is probably not possible.

Comment: The dashed lines would be nice, a more consistent form of tabulation and indentation would be nice -- exactly what one gets in Sublime. Proper syntax highlighting, as far as I know the only syntax highlighting in native Mathematica is the variables in functions turning green. Any method of keeping code and clean, readable. I love Mathematica, but it's notebook and coding formatting could do with some work!

Comment: I’m not sure what other syntax highlighting is in your screenshot? Do you just want numbers to be colored differently? Or bools? Both of those are possible. Would you like system symbols to be colored differently the same way Sublime does it? That’s also possible. As mentioned, you can’t get exactly what sublime does with the lines going down, but you can get something similarish. As for the rest of what you want, I don’t know what _exactly_ you want so I can’t answer this question.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for an IDE for the Wolfram language. If yes, please have a look at Wolfram Workbench (Eclipse plug-in) or Mathematica plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA or PyCharm. Both have nice integration with MMA kernel, so you don't need to copy your text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest, I still don't know what you're looking for since 90% of what is in your screenshot is already in Mathematica, but if you want to customize, here's something that'll do that on a single `Notebook`:

[image]

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 With[
  {
   operatorStyle = {FontColor -> GrayLevel[.3]},
   commandStyle = {FontColor -> Orange},
   blockStyle = {FontWeight -> Bold},
   typeStyle = {FontColor -> Hue[.5 , .5, .5]},
   constStyle = {FontColor -> Hue[.1 , 1, .6]},
   globalStyle = {FontColor -> Pink},
   systemStyle = {FontColor -> Black},
   customSymbolStyle = {FontColor -> Hue[.5 , .7, .2]},
   codeStyle = {
     TabFilling -> StringRepeat[" ", 11] <> "|",
     TabSpacings -> 2,
     InitializationCell -> False
     }
   },
  {
   StyleDefinitions ->
    Notebook[{
      Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
      Cell[StyleData["OperatorStyle"], Sequence @@ operatorStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["CommandStyle"], Sequence @@ commandStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["BlockStyle"], Sequence @@ blockStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["TypeStyle"], Sequence @@ typeStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["ConstantStyle"], Sequence @@ constStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["GlobalStyle"], Sequence @@ globalStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["SystemStyle"], Sequence @@ systemStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["CustomSymbolStyle"], Sequence @@ customSymbolStyle],
      Cell[StyleData["Code"], Sequence @@ codeStyle]
      }],
   AutoStyleOptions ->
    {
     "FunctionLocalVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> Blue},
     "LocalVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> Purple},
     "PatternVariableStyle" -> {FontColor -> Darker@Green, 
       FontSlant -> "Italic"},
     "SymbolContextStyles" -> {
       "System`" -> "SystemStyle",
       "Global`" -> "GlobalStyle",
       Automatic -> "CustomSymbolStyle"
       }
     },
   AutoStyleWords -> {
     "@" -> "OperatorStyle", "//" -> "OperatorStyle", "~" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     ";" -> "OperatorStyle", "," -> "OperatorStyle", "-" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "+" -> "OperatorStyle", "/" -> "OperatorStyle", "*" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "(" -> "OperatorStyle", ")" -> "OperatorStyle", "[" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "]" -> "OperatorStyle", "{" -> "OperatorStyle", "}" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "[[" -> "OperatorStyle", "]]" -> "OperatorStyle", "<" -> "OperatorStyle",
      ">" -> "OperatorStyle", ":" -> "OperatorStyle", "::" -> "OperatorStyle",
      "." -> "OperatorStyle", ".." -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "..." -> "OperatorStyle", "_" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "__" -> "OperatorStyle", "___" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "?" -> "OperatorStyle", "&" -> "OperatorStyle", "&&" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "~~" -> "OperatorStyle", "\[Rule]" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "\[RuleDelayed]" -> "OperatorStyle", "->" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     ":>" -> "OperatorStyle", "|" -> "OperatorStyle", ":=" -> "OperatorStyle",
      "^:=" -> "OperatorStyle", "/:" -> "OperatorStyle", 
     "/;" -> "OperatorStyle",
     "Return" -> "CommandStyle", "Break" -> "CommandStyle", 
     "DialogReturn" -> "CommandStyle", "Goto" -> "CommandStyle", 
     "Throw" -> "CommandStyle", "Catch" -> "CommandStyle", 
     "Message" -> "CommandStyle", "Print" -> "CommandStyle", 
     "Assert" -> "CommandStyle", "Begin" -> "CommandStyle", 
     "BeginPackage" -> "CommandStyle", "End" -> "CommandStyle", 
     "EndPackage" -> "CommandStyle",
     "With" -> "BlockStyle", "Module" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "Block" -> "BlockStyle", "If" -> "BlockStyle", "Switch" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "Which" -> "BlockStyle", "Do" -> "BlockStyle", "Table" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "For" -> "BlockStyle", "While" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "Replace" -> "BlockStyle", "ReplaceAll" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "ReplaceRepeated" -> "BlockStyle", "ReplacePart" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "Map" -> "BlockStyle", "MapIndexed" -> "BlockStyle", 
     "MapThread" -> "BlockStyle", "Entity" -> "TypeStyle", 
     "Quantity" -> "TypeStyle", "ChannelObject" -> "TypeStyle", 
     "CloudObject" -> "TypeStyle", "CloudExpression" -> "TypeStyle", 
     "CellObject" -> "TypeStyle", "Notebook" -> "TypeStyle", 
     "Cell" -> "TypeStyle", "ResourceObject" -> "TypeStyle", 
     "LocalObject" -> "TypeStyle", "FormObject" -> "TypeStyle", 
     "$Failed" -> "ConstantStyle", "False" -> "ConstantStyle", 
     "True" -> "ConstantStyle", "$Canceled" -> "ConstantStyle", 
     "All" -> "ConstantStyle"
     }
   }
  ]
 ]
```

This is based off of something I do for my own stuff, but there I put all of this in a `SyntaxHighlighting.nb` stylesheet and then link off of that. That way if you just want to make a minor adjustment to one style, you can only change that one piece. [Here's a sample](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/SyntaxHighlighting.nb) for you to work from. [Here's an example](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/CodePackage.nb) of a stylesheet deriving from it.

I'd recommend that flow to you, moving forward, but my guess is you aren't familiar with working with Mathematica stylesheets, so the function above will get you started for for some on-the-fly testing.

Comment: This already goes quite along way to what I am interested in having, so thanks for taking the time for putting together examples.

Comment: Can you tell me what you’d like to have _specifically_? I don’t know what’s left from your screenshot except the vertical bars and v12 at least seems to be buggy and not having them display

Comment: I'll edit my question to include a wishlist.